# jQuery: using remove(); for <tr> rows

Tags: jquery, removeclass

**I need to remove several `<tr>` rows in a rendered page within the table class `"form-table"`using `remove();`** *See the commented markup below*.

The problem is that there are several other tables with the class "form-table" in the rendered page *(other tables not shown below for clarity)*. Each of these other tables has a different `<h3>` heading.

Is it possible to target the last two `<tr>` rows in the table below while ignoring other tables with the same class of `form-table`? Can these two `<tr>`'s be targeted using the `<h3>Name</h3>` heading to this table?

I.e.:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $("*target <tr>'s here*").remove();

  });
```

**Rendered markup:**

```
<h3>Name</h3>

<table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="user_login">Username</label></th>
        <td><input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" value="subscriber" disabled="disabled" class="regular-text" /> <span class="description">Usernames cannot be changed.</span></td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <th><label for="first_name">First Name</label></th>
    <td><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="subscriber" class="regular-text" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th><label for="last_name">Last Name</label></th>
    <td><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" class="regular-text" /></td>
</tr>

<!-- Need to display:none or remove the two <tr>'s below: -->

<tr>
    <th><label for="nickname">Nickname <span class="description">(required)</span></label></th>
    <td><input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" value="subscriber" class="regular-text" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th><label for="display_name">Display name publicly as</label></th>
    <td>
        <select name="display_name" id="display_name">
                    <option  selected='selected'>subscriber</option>
                </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<!-- Need to display:none or remove the two <tr>'s above: -->

</table>
```

Comment: Please note that (depending on how you are targeting your `tr`'s), this may not work in Webkit due to insertion of `tbody` tags.

Comment: @ahren As long as you're specifying the `tr`s as descendants and not children, there shouldn't really be a problem.

Comment: It's more a warning than anything, and note: *depending on how you are targeting your `tr`'s*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) or [nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) function to target the specific table, then you can use `gt()` function to target all TRs greater than 2.

example 1:

```
// assuming that your target table is the first one among the other tables with the same class
var myTable = $("h3 :first").next(".form-table").find("tr:gt(2)").remove()
```

example 2:

```
// assuming that your target table's h3 has the text "Name" inside

var myTable = $("h3:contains('Name')").next(".form-table").find("tr:gt(2)").remove()
```

Comment: @Mohammed ElSayed: thanks! This works great, and in Webkit, too. I'm posting another related question on targeting a tr by label.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$('h3:contains("Name") + table tr:gt(2)')
```

Or

```
$('h3:contains("Name")').next().find('tr:gt(2)')
```

EDIT:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kMYY3/1/

Comment: Thanks! @Mohammed ElSayed was just a few minutes earlier with his answer. -- Mark

Comment: @songdogtech That's okay, but I was actually the first one with the correct answer, and corrected the others, which were wrong.

Comment: I know; I split the difference and gave you some upticks.

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
$('.form-table tr:gt(2)');  //note the index is 0 based
```

[jQuery gt selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)